# Is it possible to run only one instance of WiX msi at the same time?

Tags: wix, windows-installer, single-instance

I have .Net product with msi installer implemented using WiX. Now it is possible to run several instances of my installer at the same time. I am wondering whether it's possible to restrict run more than one instance of installer at the same time?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Only one .msi will install at a time, but you can open the UI of any number; nothing in MSI prevents it.

Comment: Actually the _MSIExecute Mutex also enforces one Install/Admin-UI sequence per process.

Comment: Arnson terseness again. I think you can open any number of setups with the GUI sequence showing simultaneously. I think the mutex is set at `InstallInitialize` (possibly sooner) and is released at `InstallFinalize`? Not that important, the overall message is clear: one install transaction at a time.